# Find maximum value of all properties in list of objects

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have the following Entity Framework Core query:

```
  IQueryable<Product> products = context.Products;

  var maximums = new MaximumModel {
    PA = await products.MaxAsync(x => x.Composition.PA)
    PB = await products.MaxAsync(x => x.Composition.PB)
    PC = await products.MaxAsync(x => x.Composition.PC)
    PD = await products.MaxAsync(x => x.Composition.PD)
    // Other 36 properties ...
  }
```

This executes 40 queries, one for each query ...

Is there a way to execute only one query?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this with EF async versions, but the LINQ to SQL solution is to use a singleton group from a `GroupBy` to combine the query into one query:

```
var maximums = await products.GroupBy(p => 1)
                             .Select(pg => new MaximumModel {
                                                PA = pg.Max(x => x.Composition.PA),
                                                PB = pg.Max(x => x.Composition.PB),
                                                PC = pg.Max(x => x.Composition.PC),
                                                PD = pg.Max(x => x.Composition.PD),
                                                  // Other 36 properties ...
                             }).FirstAsync();
```

Comment: Confirmed this works in EF and EF Core and with async flavours. An interesting approach worth noting for the future. :)